# Javascript geolocation API and the lacking callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, geolocation

Using Javascript geolocation API the user is prompted in that way:

"Would you like to use your current Location?"

Three things may happen:

1) The user choose OK
2) The user choose "Don't allow"
3) There is an error or timeout

The API available seem to be currently lacking, because I can manage (1) and (3) asyncronously with a callback, but not (2):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            alert("You pressed OK");
        },
        function(error) {
            alert("There is an error");
        }
);
```

Suppose that in case of (2) I want to do some particular operations: how can I detect this?

Answer (score 0):

All cases *can* be handled by the error callback:

> **`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)`**
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ...
>
> - `error` *Optional*
>
>   An optional callback function that takes a `PositionError` object as its sole input parameter.
>
> ...
>
> **`PositionError`**
>
> A `PositionError` object is an arbitrary JavaScript object with the following properties:
>
> ...
>
> - `code`
>
>   A number representing the error code. It can be **(1) permission denied**, (2) position unavailable, or **(3) timeout**.
>
> ...
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Example:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(..., function (e) {
    switch (e.code) {
        case 1 : // permission denied
        case 2 : // position unavailable
        case 3 : // timeout
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Firefox 28 on osx and it won't call the error() callback if the user deny to access to the geolocation api.

One possible solution is to "reverse" the logic.

```
firstDoSomething(); 

var doSomethingWithPosition = function(pos) { ... };

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(doSomethingWithPosition);
}
```